# Search an LDAP dump file for specific and related values

Tags: python, ldap

I have an LDAP dump file. I want to be able to search for a specific OU and also get values of properties directly related as well as properties of other OUs that are related. The file is over 10,000 lines and groups of related information are separated by an empty line. Example structure:

```
dn: cn=chuckSudo,ou=sudoers,dc=classy,dc=house,dc=com
objectClass: sudoRole
objectClass: top
sudoUser: wills
sudoUser: +upperusers
sudoHost: +upperhosts
sudoHost: big_velma
sudoCommand: !/usr/bin/passwd root
sudoCommand: ALL
sudoCommand: !SHELLS
cn: chuckSudo

dn: cn=upperusers,ou=users,ou=netgroup,dc=classy,dc=house,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: nisNetgroup
cn: upperusers
nisNetgroupTriple: (,randyz,)
nisNetgroupTriple: (,phillish,)
nisNetgroupTriple: (,jameyp,)

dn: cn=upperhosts,ou=hosts,ou=netgroup,dc=classy,dc=house,dc=com
cn: upperhosts
objectClass: nisNetgroup
objectClass: top
nisNetgroupTriple: (ragged_bob,,)
nisNetgroupTriple: (trusty-sue,,)
nisNetgroupTriple: (mul_holland,,)
```

I would like to use Python to be able to search the file. From the code above, if I search for "chuckSudo" I want my results to return all the sudoCommand property values and all of the nisNetgroupTriple values ffor all of the related hosts and users in the sudoUser: +upperusers
sudoHost: +upperhosts.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to deal with the specific sections (line groupings) as I'm looking through the file. Each group of lines has a different number and a variable number of properties. Thought about trying to first loop through and create a list of dictionaries with keys being the group hosts or group users and and the values being a list of all the values for those. But still would need to be able to tie those to the cn name of the sudoer. The expected output for me searching for chuckSudo would be:

```
{sudoCommand: [!/usr/bin/passwd root, ALL, !SHELLS]}
{upperUsers: [randyz,phillish,jameyp, wills]}
{upperHosts: [ragged_bob,trusty-sue,mul_holland,big_velma]}
```

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why? It would be far easier to search the LDAP directory directly. Very good tools and filters available, instead of having to handcraft something.

Comment: Yes, that would be nice, but I don't have direct access to the LDAP directory. They gave me a dump file. So working with what I've got.

Comment: Can you run your own LDAP server? Import that LDIF into it and use LDAP filter programming.

Answer (score 1):

You should really just spin up an LDAP server (there are several maintained OpenLDAP container images out there that make this easy), load your LDIF dump into the server, and then just query the data using LDAP queries and filters.

You *can* read the data in your LDIF dump using something like the [`ldif3` module](https://pypi.org/project/ldif3/). Locating a record with a given `cn` is simple:

```py
import ldif3
import json

with open('data.ldif', 'rb') as fd:
    parser = ldif3.LDIFParser(fd)
    records = parser.parse()

    for record in records:
        if record[1]['cn'][0] == 'chuckSudo':
            print("found it!")
            print(json.dumps(record[1], indent=2))
```

I'm justing the `json` module here for output formatting; it's not part of the solution.

However, you don't want to simply search for records; you want to then dynamically expand NIS group membership, which isn't something an LDAP server would do, either. You would need to first (a) scan for netgroups in the LDIF file, (b) parse the resulting `nisNetGroupTriple` values into Python data structures, and then (c) use these to resolve `+<name>` syntax in your `sudoUser`/`sudoHost` values.

Maybe something like this:

```py
import ldif3

def parse_members(spec, kind):
    members = []
    for member in spec:
        if member.startswith('+'):
            ng = member[1:]
            members.extend(netgroups[ng][kind])
        else:
            members.append(member)

    return members

with open('data.ldif', 'rb') as fd:
    parser = ldif3.LDIFParser(fd)
    records = parser.parse()

    netgroups = {}
    sudoroles = []
    for record in records:
        if 'nisNetgroup' in record[1]['objectClass']:
            grp = netgroups[record[1]['cn'][0]] = {'hosts': set(), 'users': set()}
            for triple in record[1]['nisNetgroupTriple']:
                hostname, username, domainname = triple.strip('()').split(',')
                if hostname:
                    grp['hosts'].add(hostname)
                if username:
                    grp['users'].add(username)
        elif 'sudoRole' in record[1]['objectClass']:
            sudoroles.append(record[1])

    for sudorole in sudoroles:
        print('role:', sudorole['cn'][0])
        sudousers = parse_members(sudorole['sudoUser'], 'users')
        sudohosts = parse_members(sudorole['sudoHost'], 'hosts')
        print(f'  sudousers: {", ".join(sudousers)}')
        print(f'  sudohosts: {", ".join(sudohosts)}')
```

Given your sample input, this produces:

```
role: chuckSudo
  sudousers: wills, randyz, phillish, jameyp
  sudohosts: ragged_bob, trusty-sue, mul_holland, big_velma
```